# Salt id number within the WSN

Tags: salt

I am working on a project in wireless sensor networks security, and I would like to use a salt number as id for my nodes within the network. does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: This question does not make sense at all. It is also unclear how it relates to security. You want to name the nodes in your network with a random string?

Comment: In WSN every node has an id, and I want to use 3 parameters ( MAC, IpV6 and salt number) to generate an id for every node within the networks. And I'm asking if anyone has experienced it before.

Comment: What is normally used for an ID? How does one normally set the ID? This is still not a security question.

Comment: Normally the IP addresses are used as an id, you can identify your nodes by their IP addresses. And in WSN there is a kind of network attack which the attackers can pretend to be inside the network by using the legitimate node's id to get into the network.